# In Supernatural, why didn't Castiel [Season 9 finale spoiler]

Tags: supernatural

Why didn't Castiel

> type a happy ending with Metatron's machine?  If Metatron could make his plot happen in the world with his typing, why couldn't Cas do the same?

Comment: I've not watched supernatural but this sounds extremely spoilerish...

Comment: he can't make it happen by typing it, he can however manipulate things so that his script will work out. For example, when cass refused to do what "Gabriel" told him to do.

Comment: @Simon Yep, and for the season finale that only aired this week

Comment: @Izkata Well on behalf of some people, Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

#### When the scene opens Castiel didn't know where the tablet with the "Word of God" was, nor did he know how Metatron was manipulating everyone using it.

> Rather than become like Metatron, Castiel uses Metatron's vanity to cause him to reveal his deceptions over the "Angel Radio". Castiel, feeling as if he had already failed the Angels more than once, had no interest in repeating Metatron's mistakes and destroyed this, one of the last  and most powerful artifacts in Metatron's possession.